# Как получить токен из заголовков ответа в js?

Tags: javascript, веб-сервер, fetch, cors

**Здравствуйте!**
Делаю fetch запрос на сервер для получения токена, запрос проходит успешно со статусом 200, но выдает ошибку корс. Далее сделал запрос отключив корс на стороне клиента mode: no-cors (так как на стороне сервера корс отключен и другие запросы успешно отправляются на сервер без каких либо проблем, проблемы были только с этим запросом), теперь уже ошибки корс нету, запрос прошел успешно, статус такой же (200) в браузере, если посмотреть на запрос, то виден и сам токен, который находится в заголовках, данный запрос не содержит ответа только заголовки, но когда пытаюсь получить заголовки в js (response) то там нету ни одного заголовка (все со значением null) и статус запроса 0 и поле ok со значением false.

```
const res = await fetch('https://online.mosgortur.dev:7000/TourSearchOwin/Token', {
           method: "POST",
           mode: 'no-cors',
           headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           },
           body: new URLSearchParams(obj)
})

console.log(res);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает, как я могу получить этот токен из заголовков ответа в js? Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой

Comment: А где в ответе токен? Если вы про Set-Cookie, то эти данные вы в JS никак не получите. И зачем их получать? Браузер самостоятельно отправляет куки.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Токен есть в заголовках ответа, на скрине видно, он не записывается в куки, хотел сам взять этот токен и записать его в соответствующем формате в ручную. Так же токен мне нужен для отправки некоторых запросов пользовател

Comment: Он записывается в куки того домена который в запросе (`online.mosgortur.dev:7000`). Прочитать их JS вы не сможете по трём причинам: 1) в режиме `no-cors` нельзя получить данные, 2) Заговолок `Set-Cookie` в списке запрещённых для чтения, 3) флаг `HttpOnly` запрещает доступ к куке из JS.

Comment: В общем ищите какие-то другие способы, а лучше опишите что и зачем вы делаете.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я хотел бы просто получить этот токен в js, записать его в стейтменеджер (vue) и дальше использовать в заголовках запросов для получения данных пользователя (headers - 'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'), так же мне нужно его записать в куки с определенным ключем для дальнейшего чтения и на других сервисах

Comment: Хотеть вы можете, но этот апи явно не предназначен для такого использования.

Comment: @AlexeyTen т.е как бы я не решил ошибку с корсом, используя этот апи, я не смогу получить token?

Comment: Нет, никак не получить.